# Prove that $\tan^{-1}\frac{yz}{xr} + \tan^{-1}\frac{zx}{yr} + \tan^{-1}\frac{xy}{zr} = \frac{\pi}{2} $ where $x^2 + y^2+z^2=r^2$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that

> $$ \tan^{-1}\frac{yz}{xr} + \tan^{-1}\frac{zx}{yr} + \tan^{-1}\frac{xy}{zr} = \frac{\pi}{2} $$
>   where $x^2 + y^2+z^2=r^2$

You have to use the formula :

> $$\tan^{-1}x_1 + \tan^{-1} x_2 + \tan^{-1} x_3 + \cdots\cdots = \frac{\\S_1 - S_3 + \cdots}{1-S_2+S_4-\cdots}$$

where $S_k $ denotes the sum of the product of $x_1,x_2,x_3, \cdots x_n$ taking $k$ at a time.

I didn't understand the formula correctly and therfore I was not able to find the answer.
 I think I should make it equal to  $\tan^{-1}\infty$
Thankyou

Comment: Please.  Do not write {tan^-}^1.  Write \tan^{-1}.  That is standard usage.  Your way just makes things difficult to understand, and causes $\tan$ to appear italicized and without proper spacing in expressions like $a\tan b$.

Comment: With only three terms, the formula reduces to $$\frac{S_1-S_3}{1-S_2}$$ Do you understand what each $S_k$ looks like? For instance, $S_2 = x_1 x_2 + x_1 x_3 + x_2 x_3$ (the sum of products of pairs of items from $x_1, x_2, x_3$).

Comment: thanks for the latter  ... +1

Comment: So $S_1$ is $x_1$? can you tell me what Si and S2 and S3 are?

Comment: Nope. $S_1$ is not $x_1$. $S_1$ is the sum of single items from $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$. (There are three such single items, so the sum has three terms.)

Comment: @chndn you probably copied your formula wrongly. There should be a $ \tan^{-1}$ on the right hand side too.

Answer (score 2):

$\arctan a+\arctan b+\arctan c$ will be $\frac\pi2$

if$ \arctan a+\arctan b =\frac\pi2-\arctan c$

if $ \tan(\arctan a+\arctan b) =\tan(\frac\pi2-\arctan c)$

if $ \tan(n\pi+\arctan \frac{a+b}{1-ab}) =\cot(\arctan c)=\cot(\text{arccot}\frac1c)$

if $ \frac{a+b}{1-ab} =\frac1c$

if $  ab+bc+ca=1$

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are right by saying that you should get $\tan^{-1}\infty$.
Use the definitions of $S_k$:
$$S_1=x_1+x_2+x_3=\frac{yz}{xr}+\frac{xz}{yr}+\frac{xy}{zr}$$
$$S_2=x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=\frac{z^2}{r^2}+\frac{x^2}{r^2}+\frac{y^2}{r^2}$$
$$S_3=x_1x_2x_3=\frac{xyz}{r^3}$$
So:
$$\tan^{-1}\frac{yz}{xr} + \tan^{-1}\frac{zx}{yr} + \tan^{-1}\frac{xy}{zr}=\frac{S_1-S_3}{1-S_2}=\frac{\frac{yz}{xr}+\frac{xz}{yr}+\frac{xy}{zr}-\frac{xyz}{r^3}}{1-\frac{z^2}{r^2}+\frac{x^2}{r^2}+\frac{y^2}{r^2}}$$
In the denominator you have:
$$1-\frac{z^2}{r^2}+\frac{x^2}{r^2}+\frac{y^2}{r^2}=\frac{r^2-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{r^2}=0$$
So even without dealing with the numerator you have $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cdot}{0}\right)$
But to be clear you have to compute the numerator (you can possibly have $0$ there too ;)).

 The numerator will be:
$$\frac{yz}{xr}+\frac{xz}{yr}+\frac{xy}{zr}-\frac{xyz}{r^3}=\frac{r^2(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+x^2z^2-xyz)}{r^3}$$
Which does not look like $0$. So you have $\tan^{-1}(\infty)=\frac{\pi}{2}$